# How to call requestAnimFrame on an object method?

Tags: javascript, oop, requestanimationframe

Say I have the following object:

```
function Foo(value){
    this.bar = value;
    this.update();
}
Foo.prototype.update = function(){
    console.log(this.bar);
    this.bar++;
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
}
Foo.prototype.setBar(value){
    this.bar = value;
}
```

This does not work. FireFox gives me an error:

```
NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMWindow.requestAnimationFrame]
```

I would like to know why, and what other solution could be used instead to call an object's update method without calling it from your main function(i.e. while keeping the object anonymous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` doesn’t bind `this` to anything, like any direct call. You can do that manually using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Foo.prototype.update = function(){
    console.log(this.bar);
    this.bar++;
    requestAnimationFrame(Foo.prototype.update.bind(this));
};
```

Binding permanently is another way:

```
function Foo() {
    …
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.update();
}
```

Comment: @Qqwy: Right. Manually, you could do `var that = this; requestAnimationFrame(function() { that.update(); });`.