# "Uncaught Type" error with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

So I have written a working application (actually half of it) with requestAnimationFrame. Before the project gets too complex I'm rushing to rewrite it in an object-oriented style so we can implement plugins better (and also fix modules without changing the whole app). In fact the first version of the app was really messed up and made up from a lot of test code.

So I have the following:

```js
Aventura.prototype.update = function() {
  var av = this;
  requestAnimationFrame(av.update);

  /* ... frame code ... */
};
```

And I get "Uncaught TypeError: Type error " in the console log, right in the requestAnimationFrame line. I know my browser has a proper requestAnimationFrame implementation since I used the messed up version of my app perfectly well.

I've reached the conclusion that it raises an exception because I'm calling a method that is a member of the caller's own parent object (I know it's exactly the same method, but the problem clearly isn't on self-calling since that's what RAF is supposed to do). Any clues of what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `requestAnimationFrame`. It is a basic JavaScript issue related to passing functions in general, and the meaning of `this`.

People tend to think that a function-valued property inside an object, such as `myFn` in the below

```
var myObj = {
    myFn: function() {console.log(this);}
};
```

somehow has `myObj` "baked in" as `this`. Wrong. `this` is assigned only at the time the function is *called*. If I say `myObj.myFn()`, `this` becomes `myObj`, but I could just as easily say `myObj.myFn.call(otherObj)` to have `this` be something else.

This becomes important when passing functions around as parameters to `setTimeout`, promises, or `requestAnimationFrame`. Just passing `myObj.myFn` passes the function, but it has no associated `this`. `requestAnimationFrame` has no idea where this function came from and what `this` to call it with, so it calls it with a `this` of `window`, or `null`, or 0, or `undefined`, or who knows what. This causes the error.

The simplest way to fix the problem is to simply say

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {av.update(); });
```

Now `update` is called with the correct `this`.

A more sophisticated, equivalent way, would be

```
requestAnimationFrame(av.update.bind(av));
```

### Other note

I don't think the way you're passing the function itself to `requestAnimationFrame` is going to work well. You're essentially setting up a chain of recursive calls, and eventually the stack will overflow. You need to separate the logic to be executed on the `requestAnimationFrame` callback from the logic to request the frame.

Comment: You mean the requestAnimationFrame-calling method should be separate from the update method itself?

Comment: Yes, that'w what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up finding the answer on another question here. I don't think it classifies as a duplicate though, since both questions were asked in different ways and someone could find one but not the other question (I myself seeked for a similar problem all over the web and didn't ever run into this potential duplicate).

[How to call requestAnimFrame on an object method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177297/how-to-call-requestanimframe-on-an-object-method)