# Why Angular Universal is Not working properly

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, angular-universal

I was converting my existing angular app to Angular Universal,Based on Official Angular Documentation.

After completion of build,when i navigate to port 4000,server stopped  with this error.

> ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined

These are the steps whicht i followed, based on official Documentation

1.`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject projname`

2.`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking Show us what you've tried. We can't guess what your code looks like.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20314691/3937794), might be helpful !

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` is defined in the browser, not in node where your server side application runs. Add the following code in your `server.ts` to define it plus `cancelAnimationFrame`:

```
global['requestAnimationFrame'] = function(callback, element) {
  let lastTime = 0;
  const currTime = new Date().getTime();
  const timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
  const id = setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
    timeToCall);
  lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
  return id;
};

global['cancelAnimationFrame'] = function(id) {
  clearTimeout(id);
};
```

I hope this will help!

If you run into any other issue with SSR, [check if this article already covers it](https://medium.com/@michele.patrassi/angular-ssr-firebase-save-days-of-debugging-by-reading-these-fixes-fcb060e248bb?source=friends_link&sk=62bebf17f7250c3a47d43bfb38f03786).

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: null ; Value: TypeError: window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function

Comment: I received the above error with SSR. Any idea why it is caused? I also added the above code in my server.ts

Comment: you need to define the function in your server.ts file before the universal related code. If you check the article I linked there is a snippet you could get inspiration from

Comment: I have seen that article and have also added it to the server.ts file. I am getting requestAnimationFrame is not a function error, not requestAnimationFrame is not defined error. But my universal build is being executed without any hindrance even after getting this error on console. Any idea about this?

Comment: @RevathiSekar same problem

Comment: Actually, it  is working now @DhairyTripathi

Comment: @RevathiSekar what was the problem